# First order differential equations (y'(x))^2 = a*x+b*y(x)+c

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can anyone help me please to solve this equation:

$$ (y'(x))^2 = a\cdot x+b\cdot y(x)+c \\ 
a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}  $$

Thanks :)

Comment: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. This is not the place to get your homework done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make $p=y'$ the new independent variable, $\dot p=1$, $\dot y=p\dot x$, 
$$
p^2=ax+by+c\implies 2p=a\dot x+b\dot y=(a+bp)\dot x
$$
The last equation is separable,
$$
\dot x=\frac{2p}{a+bp}=\frac2b\left(1-\frac a{a+bp}\right)
$$
which integrates to
$$
x(p)=\frac2b\left(p-\frac ab\ln|a+bp|\right)+K
$$
which allows to compute $y(p)$. The relation of $x$ to $y$ remains implicit.

---

One also needs to consider the case where $y'=M$ is constant, as along this solution one can not take $p=y'$ as (local) parameter. Then $M^2=ax+by+c$ has the derivative $0=a+bM$ which has the only solution $M=-\frac{a}{b}$ which gives the only linear solution.

Comment: Thanks. How can I compute y(p)?
$$p=x^{-1}(p)  => y'=x^{-1}(y')$$ and then just integrate?

Comment: No, not that complicated, just insert $x(p)$ into $y(p)=\dfrac{p^2-ax(p)-c}b$.

Comment: Thanks again :) 
So $ p  \rightarrow (x(p),y(p))$ is the solution?

Comment: It is one parametrization of the solution trajectories. It is as good as any other implicit solution form.

Comment: Last question:
Why is $\dot p=1$ and $\dot y=p \dot x$.
And is $ \dot p= p'$ a derivate of $p$?
How do you get 
$2p=a \dot x+b \dot y=(a+bp) \dot x$?

Comment: This is abuse of notation, more correctly you would have to set $x=X(p)$, $Y(p)=y(X(p))$ so that the relations follow per chain rule $\dot Y(p)=y'(X(p))\dot X(p)=p\dot X(p)$. The dot derivatives are for $p$, thus $\dot p=\frac{dp}{dp}=1$.